# Pandas: Escape all spaces in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
d = {'col1': ['hi there', 'what are you doing', 'cool'], 'col2': [3, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I use the dataframe to pass in command line arguments row by row to a function.

My issue is that there are spaces, so I need to escape them to be able to pass the whole line as an argument correctly

I have tried

```
df.replace(" ", "\ ").head()
```

But that didn't seem to do anything.
What is the best way to replace all spaces in my dataframe to get the output below?

Output:

```
d = {'col1': ['hi\ there', 'what\ are\ you\ doing', 'cool'], 'col2': [3, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn the `regex` on

```
out = df.replace(" ", "\ ",regex=True)
                    col1  col2
0              hi\ there     3
1  what\ are\ you\ doing     4
2                   cool     5
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.str.replace` or `.replace(..., regex=True)` to replace substrings. Also `\` is the escape character, so it'd better either use raw string or another escape:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace(' ', r'\ ')
```

Output:

```
0                hi\ there
1    what\ are\ you\ doing
2                     cool
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Output:

```
                    col1  col2
0              hi\ there     3
1  what\ are\ you\ doing     4
2                   cool     5
```